# log4net .netcore 3.1 method not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

Background:
This is a .netcore 3.1 web api. It references a DLL that references an SDK to create connections to a third party application. 
When creating the server object (in the DLL) it throws the following error:

[image: error message]

```
 .net core app
      - DLL containing legacy methods
           - DLL instantiates an SDK server object throwing log4net error
```

I've added the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore` nuget package and tried the logger factory way:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
```

I've also tried this: https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/

I have a `log4net.config` in the solution as well. Any advice on how to resolve the error?

[image]

Comment: Most likely the dll and your app has a different version of the dependency

Comment: Does this code `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net()` leads to the error. Provide the details of the package used `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore`. Also can you ensure that all the logger config mentioned in the log4net exist.

Comment: Expand the Dependencies item from the screenshot, you should see more details about the error only by hovering your mouse above the conflicting package

Comment: The code that leads to the error is in the constructor of the SDK being instantiated. The logging code in the app itself does not fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache lost the private key that they used to sign log4net assemblies, so older versions of log4net assemblies have a different public key token.

There's not enough information to know if that's what's biting you, but it sounds like it could be related.

If you have a dependency which depends on an old version of log4net with the old public key token, but you resolve a new version of log4net (either because your project references it directly or one of your other dependencies does) then you can get either assembly loading exceptions or missing method exceptions at runtime whenever the code compiled against the old log4net calls one of its methods.

[This is because the type names contain the public key token.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names#specifying-assembly-names)

The general fix for this is to ensure you only have a single version of log4net in your dependency tree (or at least all versions with the same public key token).

Comment: I am going to look into this it sounds like exactly my issue. The dll references the log4net assembly which is at least a couple years old

Comment: The project uses the nuget latest version. I tried having no references to log4net in my application (but the dll still does) and that failed at run time as well

Comment: This ended up being the issue. I put an old version of log4net with the solution and used it for all dependencies to match the dll version and it resolved the error.